# R Stacked Bar Graph problems

Tags: r, plot, graph, bar-chart

I have been trying to do a stacked bar graph by getting the counts as follows:

```
counts <- table(results$Performance, results$Country)
barplot(counts, main = "Game Count per Football Team",
        xlab = "Football Teams", ylab = "Game Count",
        col = c("darkblue","red", "Yellow"),
        legend = rownames(counts),ylim=c(0,1000)
        )
```

the counts table is this:

```
          ENG ESP ITA NED
  BETTER    330 257 264 197
  NO CHANGE 312 234 188 108
  WORSE     252 199 143  74
```

However this is the result that I am getting from the chart:

[image: Graph]

Clearly it is not reflecting the results in the table - why is this happening?

Comment: Please post results of `dput(counts)`, in that way is much easier to help you

Comment: BTW, the plot seems pretty correct... why are you saying that is wrong ? Maybe you wanted side-by-side bars ? Try adding the argument  beside=TRUE to barplot

Comment: the worse count in England is 252 but it is showing that is more than 800. I want 252 to be the bottom layer showing worse, 312 slightly above it to show no change and 330 slightly above both to show better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plot you have reflect the results of the table. The values for each column are stacked on top of each other (which is the default behaviour).

If you want to see them separately you can add `beside=TRUE` argument to the `barplot()` like so:

```
barplot(tab, beside=TRUE, legend=TRUE)
```

[image]

And if the goal is to stack them by country instead, just transpose the table:

```
barplot(t(tab), legend=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: can they be stacked for each country?

Comment: Yes, you should simply transpose the table in that case: `barplot(t(tab))`